# Multi select bootstrap dropdown option selector not always showing correct/different variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

The multi select bootstrap dropdown selector I am using now is breaking the JS I am using to show different variables based on if it is a property sale or long let i.e the price ranges.

The Javascript I am currently using is working when I select the long lets dropdown perfectly (by default on the sales option showing the sales prices), so it displays the correct monthly prices, however when I go back to the sale dropdown option, which should then bring me back to the sale prices, it stays fixed on the long lets price options.

```
    $(".select_type").change(function () {
        if ($(this).find(':selected')[0].className === "propertySalesOption") {
            $('.rentalSearch').hide();
            $('.lettingsSearch').hide();
            $('.saleSearch, .SalesRentSearch').fadeIn('fast');
            $("#longletval").val("0");
        }
        else if ($(this).find(':selected')[0].className === "longLetsOption") {
            $('.saleSearch').hide();
            $('.lettingsSearch').hide();
            $('.rentalSearch, .SalesRentSearch').fadeIn('fast');
            $("#longletval").val("1");
        }
        else if ($(this).find(':selected')[0].className === "holidayLettingsOption") {
            $('.saleSearch').hide();
            $('.rentalSearch').hide();
            $('.SalesRentSearch').hide();
            $('.lettingsSearch').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });



<select class="select_type form-control selectpicker">
        <option class="propertySalesOption">Property Sales</option>
        <option class="longLetsOption">Long Lets</option>   
</select>


<select name="MinimumPrice" class="form-control selectpicker">
            <option value="0">Min Price</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="500">&euro;500 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="600">&euro;600 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="700">&euro;700 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="800">&euro;800 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="900">&euro;900 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="1000">&euro;1.000 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="1200">&euro;1.200 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="1400">&euro;1.400 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="1600">&euro;1.600 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="1800">&euro;1.800 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="2000">&euro;2.000 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="2500">&euro;2.500 (/m)</option>                               
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="3000">&euro;3.000 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="4000">&euro;4.000 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="5000">&euro;5.000 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="10000">&euro;10.000 (/m)</option>
            <option class="rentalSearch" style="display:none;" value="15000">&euro;15.000 (/m)</option>

            <option class="saleSearch" value="50000">&euro;50.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="75000">&euro;75.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="100000">&euro;100.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="125000">&euro;125.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="150000">&euro;150.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="175000">&euro;175.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="200000">&euro;200.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="250000">&euro;250.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="300000">&euro;300.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="350000">&euro;350.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="400000">&euro;400.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="450000">&euro;450.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="500000">&euro;500.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="550000">&euro;550.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="600000">&euro;600.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="650000">&euro;650.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="700000">&euro;700.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="750000">&euro;750.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="800000">&euro;800.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="850000">&euro;850.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="900000">&euro;900.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="950000">&euro;950.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="1000000">&euro;1.000.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="1500000">&euro;1.500.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="2000000">&euro;2.000.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="2500000">&euro;2.500.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="3000000">&euro;3.000.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="3500000">&euro;3.500.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="4000000">&euro;4.000.000</option>
            <option class="saleSearch" value="4500000">&euro;4.500.000</option>
        </select>
```

When I add this JS below it works fine, however the dropdown options cut off in the container and also messes up the dropdown options in my secondary search, please see code and screenshots below:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        });            
    </script>
```

[image: screenshot home search]

[image: secondary search]

Comment: are you using bootstrap v3? did you included any other css files on your page,, I see this as not default theme, right? do you have other js files loaded that target that dropdown maybe? can you build jsfiddle for us to see live version of that behaviour?

Comment: can you share full html please

Comment: I see prices are displaying correctly: https://i.imgur.com/nyfsNlF.png in FF & Chrome

Comment: Select the “Property Sales” dropdown, click on “Long Lets”, when the “Long Lets” has been selected, the field for “Min Price” will display different prices with (/m) at the end of them (which is good), but when you then click on the selected “Long Lets” option and click on “Property Sales”, when “Property Sales” option has been selected, it does not change the priceranges back to what they should be

Comment: can you show me a peace of code is adding `/m` to the options? (I see that it's already in the source of the page) or what is hidding / showing it.. please

Answer (score 0):

I have included latest jQuery version before your javascript and it works

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script>

 $(".select_type").change(function () {
    if ($(this).find(':selected')[0].className === "propertySalesOption") {
        $('.rentalSearch').hide();
        $('.lettingsSearch').hide();
        $('.saleSearch, .SalesRentSearch').fadeIn('fast');
        $("#longletval").val("0");
    }
    else if ($(this).find(':selected')[0].className === "longLetsOption") {
        $('.saleSearch').hide();
        $('.lettingsSearch').hide();
        $('.rentalSearch, .SalesRentSearch').fadeIn('fast');
        $("#longletval").val("1");
    }
    else if ($(this).find(':selected')[0].className === "holidayLettingsOption") {
        $('.saleSearch').hide();
        $('.rentalSearch').hide();
        $('.SalesRentSearch').hide();
        $('.lettingsSearch').fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
```

Also add script tags to your javascript code.

Check it here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ww8wpwn7

Comment: You have an error on line 170 
   <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg search_by_keyword" name="Reference" placeholder="Reference" onfocus="doClear()" />
Try to comment that line and test if the selects work. If the answer is yes check doClear() function.

Comment: Also try to replace $(".select_type").change(function () .... with 
$(document).on("change",".select_type", function () ...